# RegExp in C# to get the Subject line in Email from Email body

Tags: c#, regex

Best RegExp to Get the Subject of the Email from Email body?

This is how body looks like.

```
  <b>Bcc:</b>&nbsp;<br/><b>Subject:</b> Please Confirm: This is Updated Information</FONT><br/>
```

I need this **Please Confirm: This is Updated Information**

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Subject:</b> (.+)</FONT>");
var match = regex.Match(" <b>Bcc:</b>&nbsp;<br/><b>Subject:</b> Please Confirm: This is Updated Information</FONT><br/>");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

And you should get the Subject
And then you can get the first capture group